# Error using monero-wallet-rpc: No wallet file

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

I am trying to use `monerod` and `monero-wallet-rpc` to run RPC commands to my Monero daemon with curl.

I have run `monerod` and `monero-wallet-rpc` in the following way:

1) `./monerod`

```
...
You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.
```

2) `./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 28083 --wallet-dir monerowallet --disable-rpc-login`

```
This is the RPC monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero daemon to work correctly. 
...
Starting wallet rpc server
```

3) `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:28083/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getbalance","id":"test"}' -H Content-Type: application/json"`

The response returns an error that the Monero wallet file cannot be found:

```
code: -13
message: No wallet file
```

What step am I missing? My wallet file `monerowallet` is in the same folder as `monerod` and `monero-wallet-rpc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running the command with the wrong parameters. I should have used `--wallet-file` instead of `--wallet-dir` when running `monero-wallet-rpc`.

**My corrected command:**

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 28083 --wallet-file monerowallet \
    --password mycoolpassword --disable-rpc-login
```

Comment: I'm not sure why we still allow `--password` to be supplied as an argument. On a multi-user system, this exposes your password. I'd recommend using `--prompt-for-password` if you can.